# Laravel 5 How to post comment after login

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

If unauthenticated user tries to post comment, I can catch it in Comments controller and send him to login page.

```
if(!Auth::user())
{
    return redirect()->guest('login');
}
```

But after successful login I want the comment to be automatically posted and returned to article page.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

Use `redirect()` with flash data:

```php
if (Auth::guest()) {
    $comment = $request->get('comment');
    return redirect('login')->with('comment', $comment);
}
```

Then, after authentication in the login controller, check if flashed session data exists and redirect with it:

```php
if (session('comment')) {
    return redirect('comments')->with('flash_comment', session('flash_comment'));
}
```

Read more about [flash data on Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session#flash-data)

**Update 2**

To keep the data after login, need to override the method from the `AuthenticatesUser` trait, putting this code on `\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController`:

```
protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    //backup the comment
    $comment = "";
    if (session('flash_comment')) {
        $comment = session('flash_comment');
    }

    $request->session()->regenerate();

    //sets the flash data again
    if ($comment) {
        $request->session()->flash('flash_comment', $comment);
    }

    $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

    return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
        ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}
```

**Old dummy answer**

*You could save the comment to database with a flag `active => false`. Then, when the user is authenticated, update their comments on database, setting the flag `active => true`.*

Comment: how do i know their comments if they post it unauthenticated?

Comment: The dummy answer is really dummy. It will allow unauthenticated users to flood the database. :D

Comment: after login session data is cleared, so im trying to solve this

Comment: i printed session in sendLoginResponse and there was no flash data. so your code for session regeneration must go somewhere earlier?

Comment: If you can specify a comment via a url variable (GET), does that mean I can create a url, and if you click it post a comment of my choosing?